# Intro.js with bootstrap modal and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, intro.js

I am getting an issue with **intro.js**. When I try to focus on a `Modal` it is not working.

When the page is loaded, the DOM doesn't contain the `Modal` because we use AJAX and the `Modal` is contained in a text-variable like:

```
var Xhtml = '<div class="modal fade".........'
```

I think that the problem is that the `div` isn't present while loading.

Can someone help me?

Precision: I can't write the `Modal` directly on the page.

Comment: It's seems that `intro.js` works fine with element which not in the DOM when the DOM ready. like this: http://jsbin.com/kuhopo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks a lot "Mosh Feu" for your response; but I'm Sorry, I didn't give enough precisions. I hope that I'll give enough precisions the next time.

Just a question: 

- Are you sure that when we use `$('body').append(modal);` without the <br>`$( document ).ready();`, the function is runned before the loading of DOM? 

The second problem is that we add the modal according to data user, and we don't add the modal at loading but when users do certain actions.(we refuse to add to the load)...So, can we run intro.js scripts at the same time and does it work? Thanks again!

Comment: I can't check this until Sunday. By then, please create a snippet or bin with your specific case so I could understand exactly your needs.

Comment: Sorry, I was a little bit long, but can you even see please? https://jsbin.com/buhudodowu/3/edit?html,js,output  I noticed some differences : You use intro 0.5.0 and me 2.0.0; I build my step with ".setOptions()" method... so here is

Comment: So, do you want that before move to step 3 the modal will be show then the step will focus on the field in the modal?

Comment: I want to open the automatically the modal when the user is at the step 2 and he click to next, or go to step 3 if he open the modal.

Comment: After many tries apparently It's not that easy. I'm giving up for now. Here is the bin I worked on I hope it's will help you. https://jsbin.com/vapoja/edit?html,css,js. Also, Take a look on something similar. The main difference is that the intro is **only** in the modal. [code](https://github.com/kourosh23/introjs-with-Bootstrap-Modal/blob/master/js/helpText.js), [demo](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/kourosh23/introjs-with-Bootstrap-Modal/blob/master/modal%20-%20responsive.html)

Comment: Have you got any luck how to deal with this?

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for all your responses, mosh Feu. I'll try to persist on this way, and I'll tell you if I succeed.

Comment: Sorry for not having shared home, but my colleague has succeeded using the "document.querySelector ()", it works better!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use onbeforechange() to reinspect the DOM for elements. Something like this:

```
introguide.onbeforechange(function(targetElement) {

  // Cycle through each step as defined in the options
  introguide._options.steps.forEach(function(value, key) {

    // Look for the element in the DOM
    var element = typeof value.element == 'string' ? document.querySelector(value.element) : value.element;

    // If the element now exists, update the items
    if (element) {
      introguide._introItems[key].element = element;
    }

  });

});
```

Here is your modified jsbin: https://jsbin.com/kisekofuma/edit?html,js,output

You may need some CSS tweaks to get your modal to behave but hopefully that helps.

Comment: It seems that the JavaScript `"document.querySelector('')"` works better than the jQuery's `'$('selector')'`.